# Connection to SQL Server 2016 using VBA (Excel)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to connect to a database on a SQL Server 2016. Using the Excel wizard (Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From SQL Server Database), I'm able to connect and everything works as expected.

Next I tried to connect to the server with VBA but without success:

First attempt with provider sqloledb:

```
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim con as string

Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

con = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=10.111.1.1,123456;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DB01;User ID=user123;Password=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI"

objMyConn.ConnectionString = con
objMyConn.Open
```

Another attempt with SQLNCLI11.

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sXMLResult As String

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _
         & "Server=10.111.1.1,123456" _
         & "Database=DB01;" _
         & "User ID=user123;" _
         & "Password=XXXX;" _
         & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

con.Open
```

With both code attempts I get an error

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I've tried both with the server name and IP. The port is correct.
What else could I try?  What connection string does the inbuilt "Get Data" use?

Comment: Well this is a problem, `Server=10.111.1.1,123456`. Permissible tcp/udp port numbers range from 0 to 65535.

Comment: The port is within that range. I just added a dummy number in my example.But thanks for the hint!

Comment: `Server=10.111.1.1,123456` also doesn't have a semicolon after it so it runs into the next connection string parameter `Server=10.111.1.1,123456Database=DB01;`.

Comment: perhaps you need to specify the instance ? Server=myServerName\theInstanceName

Comment: if you can connect manually, just inspect the connection it created: Data / Connections

Comment: Also, according to [ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) Connection String Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client#activex-data-objects-ado-connection-string-keywords) you should be using `Data Source=...` instead of `Server=...` and `Initial Catalog=...` instead of `Database=...` for ADODB connections. I'm surprised it's not complaining about an invalid connection string.

Comment: Added a semicolon but didn't help. Tried with colon before the port, didn't work either. changed the connection string accoring to AlwaysLearning, didn't help either. There is no instance name on my server. Checked that in ssms, view connection properties.

Comment: I inspected the connection properties after mannually creating a connection. There is no connection visible, just a query with Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDB.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location =TABLENAME; I don't know how I can use this in VBA

Comment: I've tried both Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library and 6.1 in the VBA references.

Comment: Also tried this connection string: Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;